# Is there a way of grouping multiple windows in a single window?

Tags: xmonad, terminator

Since I use XMonad as my window manager, I've found the application [terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html) (which allows a single application window to be split into multiple terminal emulators) to be extremely useful since it allows me to have a tiled terminal application open in a tabbed environment.

Is it possible to 'wrap' multiple applications into a single window, much as terminator does with its terminal windows?